# Можно ли как-то заменить макрос

Tags: c++

У меня в коде часто встречается ситуация, что к одной и той же переменной нужно обращаться много-много раз.

Предположим, что есть структура

```
struct S{
  std::vector<size_t> vector_in_s;
};
```

И еще одна, которая хранит первую

```
struct V{
  std::vector<S> vector_in_v;
};
```

Теперь я начинаю это как-то использовать

```
int main(){
  V str_v;

  str_v.vector_in_v[12].vector_in_s[7] = 0;  // A
  str_v.vector_in_v[11].vector_in_s[3] = 9;  // B
  str_v.vector_in_v[88].vector_in_s[8] = 3;  // C
  
  // auto& A = str_v.vector_in_v[12].vector_in_s[7];
  // auto& B = str_v.vector_in_v[11].vector_in_s[3];
  // auto& C = str_v.vector_in_v[88].vector_in_s[8];
  // Так я сделать не могу, потому что, когда я добавляю что-то в вектор, он может
  // перевыделить память и все ссылки становятся недействительными
  // Приходится каждый раз прописывать полностью, потому что я не могу объявить три ссылки

  if (str_v.vector_in_v[12].vector_in_s[7] != str_v.vector_in_v[11].vector_in_s[3]){
    str_v.vector_in_v[12].vector_in_s[7].emplace_back(33);
    str_v.vector_in_v[11].vector_in_s[3].emplace_back(2);
  }
}
```

Я нашел решение - макрос

```
  #define A str_v.vector_in_v[12].vector_in_s[7]
  #define B str_v.vector_in_v[11].vector_in_s[3]
  #define C str_v.vector_in_v[88].vector_in_s[8]
```

Тогда код принимает вид

```
int main(){
  V str_v;

  #define A str_v.vector_in_v[12].vector_in_s[7]
  #define B str_v.vector_in_v[11].vector_in_s[3]
  #define C str_v.vector_in_v[88].vector_in_s[8]

  if (A != B){
    A.emplace_back(33);
    B.emplace_back(2);
  }

  #undef A
  #undef B
  #undef C
}
```

Но мне не нравится такая практика; хочется избавиться от макросов и заменить это 'чем-нибудь'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз ссылка не подходит, тогда лямбда.

```
auto foo = [&]() -> auto & {return str_v.vector_in_v[12].vector_in_s[7];};
foo().emplace_back(42);
```

Comment: Интересно, сильно ли такая лямбда замедляет код?

Comment: нет, не замедлит принципиально, но функция как внизу заметно лучше. Тем более, можно сделать членом структуры?

Comment: @AntonMitrochin Если оптимизации включены, то замедляет не сильнее чем макрос.

Answer (score 2):

а почему бы не написать функцию

```
int get(int index_v, int index_s)
{
return str_v.vector_in_v[index_v].vector_in_s[index_s]
}
```

upd

```
struct S{
  std::vector<size_t> vector_in_s;
  size_t operator()(int index) { return vector_in_s[index]; }
};


struct V{
  std::vector<S> vector_in_v;
  S operator()(int index) { return vector_in_v[index]; }
};

V str_v;
str_v(12)(7).emplace_back(42);
// Правильность не гарантирую, но смысл вот такой
```

Comment: Часто бывает, что сам индекс писать очень долго, например auto& A = str_v.vector_in_v[vector_1[vector_2[vector_3[12]]]].vector_in_s[vector_3[vector_9[vector_3[7]]]]; Тогда количество кода почти не сократится

Comment: может стоит подумать о двух функциях? и как минимум читаемость улучшится

Comment: можно у каждоый из структур переопределить оператор круглые скобки и вызвать str(9)(12)

Comment: можно. но нужно смотреть в суть задачи. может там есть куда красивее решение. Например, использовать `std::pair<int,int>`

Answer (score 2):

Вам точно надо именно

```
struct S{
  std::vector<size_t> vector_in_s;
};

struct V{
  std::vector<S> vector_in_v;
};
```

а не

```
vector<vector<size_t>> v;
```

И все ваши обращения тогда вырождаются в выражения вроде

```
v[5][10] = 7;
```

Зачем именно структуры?

Comment: а кто его знает, может у человека в этих структурах ещё два десятка переменных.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать посредством создания объекта-запроса, инкапсулирующего обращение по индексу. Такой подход также позволит в перспективе добавить удобные методы для реализации дополнительных операций, например для обращения к соседним элементам и т.п.

```
class
t_Query final
{
    private: ::std::size_t m_outer_index;
    private: ::std::size_t m_inner_index;
    
    public: explicit constexpr
    t_Query(::std::size_t const outer_index, ::std::size_t const inner_index) noexcept
    :   m_outer_index{outer_index}
    ,   m_inner_index{inner_index}
    {
        return;
    }
    
    public: auto &
    operator [](V & container) const noexcept
    {
        return container.vector_in_v[m_outer_index].vector_in_s[m_inner_index];
    }
    
    public: auto const &
    operator [](V const & container) const noexcept
    {
        return container.vector_in_v[m_outer_index].vector_in_s[m_inner_index];
    }
};

int main()
{
    V str_v;
    constexpr t_Query const loca{12, 7};
    constexpr t_Query const locb{11, 3};
    // ...
    loca[str_v] = 3;  
    locb[str_v] = 9;  
    if (loca[str_v] != locb[str_v])
    {
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```